# each-in in the template is not get re-rendered when key is deleted from data source

Tags: ember.js

Inside the controller, I have the following code,

```
export default Controller.extend({
  session: service(),

  cards: {},

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    const uid = this.get('session.data.authenticated.user.uid');

    const databaseRef = firebase.database()
      .ref(`cards/${uid}`);

    const cards = this.get('cards');

    databaseRef.on('child_added', data => {
      const card = data.val();
      this.set(`cards.${card.key}`, card);
    });

    databaseRef.on('child_changed', data => {
      const card = data.val();
      this.set(`cards.${card.key}`, card);
    });

    databaseRef.on('child_removed', data => {
      const card = data.val();
      const cards = this.get('cards');
      delete cards[card.key];
      this.set('cards', cards);
    });
  }
```

In my template,

```
{{#each-in cards as |key card|}}
  {{card-item
    card=card
  }}
{{/each-in}}
```

It is working perfectly fine when there is new card been added into the `cards` object. However, when I delete card from the object using `delete this.get('cards')[card.key]` the list does not getting re-rendered.

I have confirmed that the data source is changed by logging out the state of cards after the child_removed event is triggered.

Am I missing anything?

**Update**

I can make it re-renders template by re-assign a deep cloned `cards` object to it but that is pretty expensive because the entire cards list need to get re-rendered.

```
databaseRef.on('child_removed', data => {
  const card = data.val();
  const cards = this.get('cards');
  delete cards[card.key];

  const cardsStr = JSON.stringify(cards);
  this.set('cards', JSON.parse(cardsStr));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `notifyPropertyChange`:

```
delete cards[card.key];
cards.notifyPropertyChange(card.key);
```

Comment: `cards` is a plain JS object and has no function `notifyPropertyChange`. Should I create it as Ember object instead at the first place?

Comment: I solved the issue by creating `cards` as `new Ember.object()`

Answer (score 0):

> The {{#each-in}} helper does not observe property changes to the object passed into it. In the above example, if you were to add a key to the component's categories property after the component had rendered, the template would not automatically update.
>
> In order to cause a component to re-render after you have added, removed or changed a property from an object, you need to either set() the property on the component again, or manually trigger a re-render of the component via rerender():

Refer old guide: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/templates/displaying-the-keys-in-an-object/#toc_re-rendering

If you are in Component then you can call [rerender](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Component.html#method_rerender) (its slow), else you can call [notifyPropertyChange](https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Observable.html#method_notifyPropertyChange) like Lux mentioned.